# Display a pop up youtube video on home-page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a plugin for wordpress, or do you know how to display a fancyBox or lightbox, or pop-up or whatever with a youtube video when the home page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

to manage that manually without any plugin, put the following code in your blog post

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/THECODEOFTHEVIDEO" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to find the correct link on Youtube click on `share` then `embed` and you copy past the html code that will be displayed

Comment: Well, I have found this. There are great plugins but you must pay for it. I was searching for a free one. http://www.designrazzi.com/2013/wordpress-popup-plugins/

Comment: ok, so my answer enters in the "whatever" section you expose in your question ;)